# Single Page Website Loading data into a container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a single page site that has containers which act as stops from the navigation links at the top of the screen which you can read that particular containers information. I have a button to Read More and here is the problem.

I am working on a services page that has a overview of services but I am trying to get a button that the user can click to learn more but I would like that services.html file to load into that container without leaving the current location on the page ie the new information would slide in from the right so the user can read and once done they can close the loaded information and still be where they were currently at in the one page site. I hope that makes sense? Thank you for your help!

I have tried calling the page via a `<li>` tag and a `href` but I get information cant be loaded.

```
<section class="single-items center-block parallax" id="corporate" style="background-color: cadetblue">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-11">
            <div class="area-heading text-start wow fadeInLeft">
                <h3 class="area-title text-capitalize alt-font text-white mb-2 font-weight-100">
                    <a data-fancybox="group-three" href="images/single-portfolio3.jpg">Complete <strong>Services</strong></a>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-white">For a full list click below</p>
                <a class="btn btn-transparent-white btn-rounded btn-large mt-4" data-fancybox="group-three" href="images/single-portfolio3.jpg">View More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-4 col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
    <a data-fancybox="group-three" data-thumb="images/gallery-thumb1.jpg" href="images/gallery-thumb1.jpg"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="group-three" data-thumb="images/gallery-thumb2.jpg" href="images/gallery-thumb2.jpg"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="group-three" data-thumb="images/gallery-thumb3.jpg" href="images/gallery-thumb3.jpg"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="group-three" data-thumb="images/gallery-thumb4.jpg" href="images/gallery-thumb4.jpg"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="group-three" data-thumb="images/gallery-thumb5.jpg" href="images/gallery-thumb5.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I get it but can you add your code? that would be much better to visualize.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not but here is the section I am working on.

Comment: Can `services.html` be opened as a separate page, or is it designed to always be opened as a part of something else? That's to say - does the code of `services.html` have `<html><head>....</head><body>...</body></html>` of its own?

Comment: Hi FiddlingAway, im trying to get services to open into the container instead of opening in a new window in order to keep the user engaged. Is there a way to remove the html and head tags etc and get the information to load into the container? I am trying to have the user not have to use the back arrow or close a new window unless its a icon back arrow to slide back to the previous information all while staying at the same positional container location if that makes sense?